# App OpenStreetMap for Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, libraries, openstreetmap

I would like to do a mobile native app (Android & iOS) with OpenStreetMap. I need to work with maps offline for trekking.

I read about OSMDroid, MapsForge for Android, but I need to do in iOS too. Could you recommend me some libraries, tips etc for these mobile OS?

Thank you

Comment: Library recommendations are completely off-topic here. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [OSM "stackexchange like" help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/) might be a better place for this question.

See for example: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8066/ios-android-sdk

Check also the OSM wiki: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks for possible alleys to explore.

If you are ok with a commercial library check out [skobbler's OSM SDK](http://developer.skobbler.com) - they offer offline maps and a free tier plan that might be large enough for your needs. (minus the marketing talk, the SDKs can be downloaded [here](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download))

If you are an company/enterprise then also have a look at [cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/solutions/navigation-guidance) (as far as I know they changed their policy and supported only enterprise plans).